# Pass php variable via js/jquery redirect url function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my php i'd like to redirect via javascript/jquery a url with a php variable via js function.

My js function

```
function Redirect(url){
  document.location.href=url;
}
```

In my php page i try in this way but I fear there is a problem with the syntax in the $url.

```
if ($opz = 1){

  $url = "index.php?opz=OK#PG2&id=" . $_GET['id'];

  echo "<script>";
  echo "$(function(){ Redirect($url); });";
  echo "</script>";
}
```

If I try to redirect in this way everything works perfectly (no Redirect function).

```
echo "<script>
          document.location.href='index.php?opz=OK#PG2&id=$_GET[id]'
      </script>";
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the correct syntax to pass my php variable via the js Redirect function? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the *generated* HTML and [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `echo "$(function(){ Redirect($url); });";` to

```
echo "$(function(){ Redirect('$url'); });";
```

Notice the quotes. the url is to be passed to the Redirect function as a string. So enclose it in single quotes. like `Redirect('$url');`

Answer (score 2):

your problem is simple:

```
  echo "$(function(){ Redirect($url); });";
```

should be replaced with

```
  echo "$(function(){ Redirect('$url'); });";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are trying to redirect your webpage using javascript.

You can do it with PHP also. Use PHP [`header()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp) function to redirect your page.

```
if ($opz = 1){

  $url = "index.php?opz=OK#PG2&id=" . $_GET['id'];

  header("Location:".$url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Javascript code being generated is OK try `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
if ($opz = 1){
 $param = 'opz='.urlencode("OK#PG2").'&id='.$_GET['id'];

$url = "index.php?".$param;

echo "<script>";
echo "$(function(){ Redirect($url); });";
echo "</script>";
}
```

and pick up **opz** using **urldecode();**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that your *generated HTML* looks like this:

```
Redirect(index.php?opz=.....);
```

As you can see, you're missing quotes.

To put a variable from PHP into JavaScript, I *always* use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode). This ensures that, no matter what I pass it, JavaScript will see the same thing. It takes care of quoting, escaping, even iterating over arrays and objects.